# How to bind virtual ip to outgoing traffic?

Tags: centos

I created virtual ip on interface with the following command in centos.

ifconfig eth0:0 10.100.0.5/24 broadcast 10.100.0.255

real ip of the interface is 10.100.0.3. When I ping another host
my source ip is 10.100.0.3 which is not something I want.
I want virtual IP to appear as source.

I tried to add default gateway interface eth0:0 but in route -n
still shows me eth0 as default gateway interface.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this using the 'ip' tool from the iproute-package.

Using `ip route` I can see which address is used as the source:

```
root@testbox:~# ip route
10.100.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.0.3/24  metric 1 
default via 10.100.0.1 dev eth0  proto static
```

And by copying and editing the line from above, I can change it:

`ip route change 10.100.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.0.5/24  metric 1`

`route -n` will still show eth0 as it doesn't see virtual interfaces.

Comment: mark as correct answer!